# centos 7 kvm error trying to guestmount qcow2 image

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization

I have a CentOS 7 KVM host. A partition on one of the VM's seems to be corrupt. Image is qcow2. When trying to mount the image to troubleshoot I receive the following error:

```
[root@vmhost02 images]# guestmount -a cpanel-vm.qcow2 -m /dev/sbcd /mnt/temp
libguestfs: error: vfs_type: vfs_type_stub: /dev/sbcd: No such file or directory
libguestfs: error: mount_options: mount_options_stub: /dev/sbcd: No such file or directory
guestmount: '/dev/sbcd' could not be mounted.
guestmount: Did you mean to mount one of these filesystems?
guestmount:     /dev/sda1 (xfs)
guestmount:     /dev/centos/home (xfs)
guestmount:     /dev/centos/root (xfs)
guestmount:     /dev/centos/swap (swap)

[root@vmhost02 images]# guestmount -a cpanel-vm.qcow2 -m /dev/centos/root /mnt/temp
libguestfs: error: mount_options: /dev/centos/root on / (options: ''): mount: mount /dev/mapper/centos-root on /sysroot failed: Structure needs cleaning
guestmount: '/dev/centos/root' could not be mounted.
```

I am unsure of how to repair this as I can only use guestmount to my knowledge to access the partition but that is failing?

Comment: I get the following error when trying to mount the filesystem using guestfish:                                ><fs> mount /dev/centos/root /
libguestfs: error: mount: /dev/centos/root on / (options: ''): mount: mount /dev/mapper/centos-root on /sysroot failed: Structure needs cleaning

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if that device `/dev/sbcd` isn't correct. You could try using `guestfish` first to boot the VM. From within `guestfish` you can then list the filesystems available.

For example, say I have a qcow2 file called `disk`:

```
$ guestfish --rw -a disk
Welcome to guestfish, the guest filesystem shell for
editing virtual machine filesystems and disk images.
Type: 'help' for help on commands
      'man' to read the manual
      'quit' to quit the shell
><fs> run
 100% ⟦▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒⟧ 00:00
```

You can then list the filesystems like so, and even attempt to mount them:

```
><fs> list-filesystems
/dev/sda1: xfs
><fs> mount /dev/sda1 /
```

Once mounted you can look at, here I'm looking at the `/etc/shadow` file:

```
><fs> edit /etc/shadow
...
root:$6$2c908VsVmGs.TSdO$eiSIj7k1vqMAQaW1ipKYxWhNFXYIaXHN1XbQ00oi8ZeDcR4QNo2aN4pCpmU8tP8KjwyXeyng5q3sAxT/XQO8n.:16259:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:16231:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:16231:0:99999:7:::
adm:*:16231:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:16231:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:16231:0:99999:7:::
shutdown:*:16231:0:99999:7:::
halt:*:16231:0:99999:7:::
...
```

When you're done quit it:

```
><fs> edit /etc/shadow
><fs> quit
$
```

Comment: Sorry I just put in /dev/sbcd to get a list of mountable options, then tried to mount /dev/centos/root which is when i have the error occur. It looks like the xfs file system is corrupt and needs repairing, I will try guestfish thank you!